# Openshift: Cannot upgrade to Wordpress 3.9

Tags: wordpress, openshift

My Wordpress installation offers mean update to 3.9.

I click on `Update now` and the update process is started and finishes successfully.

However, then I am still presented with the same update screen. It seems that the update is not applied for some reasons. Any ideas?

[image: Start the update process]

[image: After the update process]

Comment: How did you originally install WordPress onto your gear?  Was it a custom installation or did you use one of our quickstarts?

Comment: I used the official quickstart provided in the web interface at openshift.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After you run the upgrade from within the wordpress admin, restart your application, either using rhc app restart  command, or click the restart button in the web console, then it will tell you that a database upgrade is required.  Click the button and everything should be upgraded to wordpress 3.9.

Comment: And I was already wondering why my application suddenly has been successfully upgraded. Somehow the application must have restarted itself and now the update has been applied. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's not working for me! It updates to 3.9.2 but then offers to download 3.9.2 again! =( http://i.imgur.com/ouAoDPx.png

Comment: But this worked! =) http://druss.pp.ua/2013/11/synchronize-openshift-application-after-update/